# Getting started with pycolab and ai safety gridworlds

Tags: machine-learning

I have installed pycolab and the ai-safety-gridworlds environments and can play those grid world environment 'games' as a human player but I cannot find any literature or documentation on how to write code to interact with the games programmatically - which I'd like to do in order to begin evolving some AI systems to play them.

TY